# Inflection point and curvature

Tags: graphics, calculus-and-analysis, fitting, interpolation

Through a coordinates list and then interpolating them I got a $f[x]$.

```
f[x_] = 0.0000476869 x^4 - 0.00924801 x^3 + 0.68087 x^2- 23.0869 x + 322.355;
data = {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[20, 60, 10];
image1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 20, 60},
  Epilog->{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]},
  PlotRange-> {{-5, 70}, {-5, 70}}, AspectRatio -> 1];
```

I made a change to one of the values of original list coordinates to change the result of the curvature.

```
newdata = ReplacePart[data, {2, 1} -> 33.5];
Clear[x];
image2 = Fit[newdata, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
Plot[image2, {x, 20, 60}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[newdata]},
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 70}, {-5, 70}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Is there anything that allows me to identify the "Inflection point" and show me a "Curvature Plot" for this function?

Here is an example created by `SolidWorks`:

[image]

[Teory](http://math.tutorvista.com/calculus/points-of-inflection.html?view=simple)

[Inflexion Point Calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=c76b1b218228841bbae6a672d1fc5674&title=Inflection%20Point%20Calculator&theme=blue&i0=2x%5E3%20-%206x%5E2%20%2B%206x%20-%205&podSelect=&includepodid=Input&includepodid=Result&includepodid=Plot&podstate=Result__Show%20details&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's rename things slightly to make it more consistent

```
g = Fit[newdata, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
```

To find inflection points, you can just put (blue) points where the second derivative is zero.

```
Plot[g, {x, 20, 60}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[newdata],
   Blue, Point[{x, g} /. Solve[D[g, {x, 2}] == 0]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 70}, {-5, 70}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: 1]

To make a fancier plot we could look up an [Evolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute).  Now the radius of curvature is infinite at an inflection point, so we will actually just use the curvature.  We also need a scaling factor to see it on the plot.

```
ClearAll@evolute;
evolute[{x_, y_}, t_, s_] := 
  {x, y} + s (D[x, t] D[y, {t, 2}] - 
    D[x, {t, 2}] D[y, t])/(D[x, t]^2 + D[y, t]^2)^2 {-D[y, t], D[x, t]}

e = evolute[{x, g}, x, 200];

ParametricPlot[{{x, g}, e}, {x, 20, 60}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[newdata], Blue, Point[{x, g} /. 
   Solve[D[g, {x, 2}] == 0]],
   Blue, Opacity[0.5], Table[Line[{{x, g}, e}], {x, 20, 60, 0.5}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 70}, {-5, 70}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: 2]

[image: gif]

Comment: If the fitted function had been defined as `g[x_] = Fit[newdata, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]`, then it would have been easier to use `MeshFunctions` to mark the inflexion points, by then adding the settings `Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshFunctions -> {g''[#] &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.02]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Where these settings should be added? You could add as a answer?

Comment: @Leandro, add them in `ParametricPlot[]`; those are options for that function.

Comment: @wxffles You could, at least, show me a way so that i can generate an animation, as you did, varying the values yielded by this function: `e = evolute[{x, g}, x, 200]`?

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho `Export["foo.gif", Table[e = evolute[{x, g}, x, 300 (1 + Cos[a])]; ParametricPlot[...], {a,0,2Pi,2Pi/32}]]`

Comment: What was your source of information to describe the function pure "evolute"? If possible, could no longer available some link?

Answer (score 3):

You can hard code the curvature and apply it to your image2 and plot it.  Then the inflection points are where the curve intersects the horizontal axis.  Use the code below after your code.  I find that there are two inflection points.

```
curvature[x_] := D[#, {x, 2}]/Sqrt[1 + D[#, x]^2]^(3/2) &;

k[x_] = curvature[x][image2]

Plot[k[x], {x, 20, 60}]
```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: This formula is wrong: there shouldn't be the `Sqrt`: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_the_graph_of_a_function).