# Evolute, Involutes

Tags: plotting

I know that Mathematica can draw the evolute and the involutes of a curve. What is the line of command that I should use, say for drawing the evolute of a parabola $y=x^2$? Sorry for the triviality of my question.

Comment: See [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EvolutesOfSomeBasicCurves/) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119771/22013).